# Strings in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

How to count sub-strings in a string?

Example: findSubstrings("foxcatfox","fox") # should return 2

Comment: This isn't really a problem one would typically use recursion for. Recursion is great for things with depth (so graphs/trees/etc) but here you just have a string so a loop would be more suitable.

Comment: what about [str.count()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)? like `"foxcatfox".count("fox")` Why the recursion? And do you want to count overlapping hits or not?

Answer (score 0):

If recursion is really a must, you can try dividing the problem first.

Say if you found a matching substring at position `i`, then the total number of substring is `1 + findSub(string[i+1:], sub)`, so you can write something like this:

```
def findSubstringsRecursive(string, substring):
    counter = 0
    substringLength = len(substring)
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == substring[0]:
            end = i + substringLength
            sub1 = string[i:end]
            if substring == sub1:
                return 1 + findSubstringsRecursive(string[i+1:], substring)
    return 0
```

Comment: This is not a purely recursive approach though. The matching substring is found in an iterative manner. The recursion is then kind of forced in :)

Comment: @schwobaseggl but iteration can almost always be rearranged into recursion, no?

Comment: Yeah, the point of such an obviously academic exercise most often is to see the aesthetic and implementational simplicity of recursive solutions. I think that point is kind of lost in this mixture. The lack of simplicity can be seen as you did not even get rid of the obsolete `counter` ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following pure recursive approach is simple enough (apart from the `bool->int` coercion):

```
def findRec(s, pat):
    if len(s) < len(pat):  # base case should be obvious
        return 0
    return (pat == s[:len(pat)]) + findRec(s[1:], pat)  # recurse with smaller size

>>> findSubstrings('foxcatfox', 'fox')
2
>>> findSubstrings('foxcatfox', 'foxc')
1
>>> findSubstrings('foxcat', 'dog')
0
```

I should note that this counts overlapping occurrences which may or may not be desired. One might also add protection against or define behaviour for an empty `substring`.

Comment: This is going to exceed max depth (default 1000) if the string itself is too long.

Comment: @iBug Which is the case for the recursive approach to any problem if the problem size is too big...

Comment: OP's code looks for overlapping occurrences, so yours should be fine to go with.